# Problem autoFocus Autocomplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am not able to `focus` on the first element of my form which is an Autocomplete component of the Material UI.

When opening the modal, the focus is on the 'unit' element, as shown in the image below:
[It dont's work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnJeh.png)

I want the focus to be on the 'group' element, as shown below:
[It work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xm4v.png)

Here is the Sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bassi-zjp50?file=/src/MyForm.jsx:1422-1431

can anyone help me?

**MyForm**

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Input from "./components/Input";
import Autocomplete from "./components/Autocomplete";

const initialValues = {
  id: 0,
  group: {
    value: 0,
    label: ""
  },
  name: "",
  unit: {
    value: 0,
    label: ""
  }
};

const groupList = [
  {
    value: "1",
    label: "Seeds"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "Fertilizers"
  }
];

const unitList = [
  {
    value: "1",
    label: "kg"
  },
  {
    value: "2",
    label: "t"
  }
];

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  group: Yup.object().shape({
    value: Yup.number().required().min(1).nullable()
  }),
  name: Yup.string().required().max(50),
  unit: Yup.object().shape({
    value: Yup.number().required().min(1).nullable()
  })
});

export default function MyForm() {
  function _onSubmit(fields, { props, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {
    console.log(fields);
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={_onSubmit}
    >
      {function Render({ errors, touched, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) {
        return (
          <Form id="form">
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Field
                  name="group"
                  autoFocus
                  component={Autocomplete}
                  label="Group"
                  options={groupList}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  textFieldProps={{
                    fullWidth: true,
                    margin: "dense",
                    variant: "outlined"
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  fullWidth
                  label="Name"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  component={Input}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Field
                  name="unit"
                  component={Autocomplete}
                  label="Unit"
                  options={unitList}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  textFieldProps={{
                    fullWidth: true,
                    margin: "dense",
                    variant: "outlined"
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

**Popup Modal**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
  Grid,
  Box
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialogWrapper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    position: "absolute",
    top: theme.spacing(5)
  },
  dialogTitle: {
    paddingRight: 0
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
    textTransform: "none"
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: "0 0 auto",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  buttons: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  loadingIcon: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

function Popup(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { title, children, openPopup, setOpenPopup, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Dialog
      {...rest}
      open={openPopup}
      maxWidth="sm"
      classes={{ paper: classes.dialogWrapper }}
    >
      <DialogTitle dividers="true" className={classes.dialogTitle}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="div" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </DialogTitle>
      <Divider />
      <DialogContent {...rest} direction="row">
        {children}
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions {...rest}>
        <Grid {...rest} container className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
          <Box {...rest} className={classes.buttons}>
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              type="submit"
              form="form"
              {...rest}
            >
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              fullWidth
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenPopup(false);
              }}
              {...rest}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default Popup;
```

**Autocomplete**

```
import React from "react";
import { FieldProps, getIn } from "formik";
import { TextField, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import MuiAutocomplete, {
  createFilterOptions
} from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const NewAutocomplete: React.FC<
  FieldProps & {
    label?: string,
    options: Array<{ label: string, value: number }>
  }
> = ({ textFieldProps, field, form, label, options, isLoading, ...props }) => {
  const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
    matchFrom: "start",
    limit: 500
  });
  const errorText =
    getIn(form.touched, field.name) && getIn(form.errors, field.name);

  const valueInit = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: ""
    }
  ];

  return (
    <MuiAutocomplete
      {...props}
      {...field}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      options={[...valueInit, ...options]}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => (option ? option.label : "")}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.value === value?.value}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      loading={isLoading}
      value={field.value}
      onChange={(e, value) => {
        form.setFieldValue(field.name, value);
      }}
      renderInput={(props) => (
        <>
          <TextField
            {...props}
            {...textFieldProps}
            label={label}
            helperText={errorText?.value || errorText}
            error={!!errorText}
            autoFocus
            InputProps={{
              ...props.InputProps,
              endAdornment: (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <CircularProgress color="primary" size={20} />
                  ) : null}
                  {props.InputProps.endAdornment}
                </React.Fragment>
              )
            }}
          />
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default NewAutocomplete;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually setting `autoFocus` to `true` on `TextField` by default inside your `NewAutocomplete` definition (src/components/Autocomplete.jsx:50 in your sandbox).

Once that line removed, you can then add `autoFocus: true` to `textFieldProps` value of your first `Field` in `MyForm` component.

See [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-elgamal-76mkp?file=/src/MyForm.jsx:1615-1631)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!!!